# Unable to debug code in node modules after angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I have an library project and a application project which are upgraded recently to angular 12 from angular 9.

Before the upgrade when we have to temporarily change the library for debugging, we used to update the respective file in `node_modules/library/fesm2015` folder and the change used to reflect in the browser.

But after the recent upgrade this is not possible. The paths `node_modules/library/fesm2015` as well as `node_modules/library/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015` has the code but when we update the code in them, the change is not reflecting in the browser.

I have tried changing `compilationMode` in `angularCompilerOptions` to `partial` in the library and still the changes were not reflecting.

I was trying to look for a solution as the library is very large and it would take some substantial time to compile it every time.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Is this related to a library you control?

Comment: No. I suspect this is due to the changes in the ivy compiler. Unlike ngcc, I believe ivy places the compiled code in memory? Not sure.

Comment: @MikeOne, yes. Sorry my bad. We have a library of our own which during dev, we used to just compile it and replace it in the node_modules of the app and the UI used to reflect the changes. But after switching to ivy from ngcc, we have to restart the app for the changes to show up.

Comment: @KrishnaThota you found any solution ?